# How to search a unknown composite key for dictionary in O(1) in c#

Tags: c#, search, dictionary, time-complexity, composite-key

My key is composite key

```
public struct Mykey{
    public int index;
    public string known1;
    public string known2;
}
```

I want get key with max index by known1 and known2, my code as follows

```
 Dictionary<key, value> dict = new Dictionary<key, value>();
 // below O(n) operation
 dict.Where( k => (k.Key.known1 =="str1") && (k.Key.known2=="str2")).Max(k => k.Key.index);
```

MSDN :Dictionary Getting or setting the value of this property approaches an O(1) operation

```
dict[key] = item ;// MSDN sample O(1) key known
```

Is there possible approach O(1) to get max index for unknown composite key like MSDN sample?

Comment: You expect multiple `Mykey` objects to contain `str1` and `str2` as values? Also, what is the `TValue` you're storing? As you don't seem to need it at all.

Answer (score 1):

No if you want to do it on your existing dictionary.

As an option - build additional index (dictionary) by your "known" part of the key and store sorted list (or heap) of items for each key. It'll get search to be O(1), but add/remove will go up to O(log N) to support sort order.